# Put string with space as argument to script running as another user

Tags: ubuntu, bash

I created bash script to excuted wp cli as another user, but has problem put string with space.

My Bash Script:

```bash
user=$1
domain=$2
post_title='post title example'
post_content='post content example'

path="/home/$user/web/$domain/public_html"

su - $user -s /bin/bash -c 'wp post create --post_title='\'$post_title\'' --post_content='\'$post_content\'' --path='$path'' 2>&1
```

It return error:

```bash
title: -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
title: -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this aporoach:

```bash
su - "$user" -s /bin/bash -c 'wp post create --post_title='\'"$post_title"\'' --post_content='\'"$post_content"\'' --path='"$path"'' 2>&1
```

Comment: Yeah it worked, thank you

Comment: I'll add a little more explanation when I'm back in town